# Is "Implement Improvement" awkward English?

Tags: verbs

Do native English speakers use **implement** with **improvement** directly?

I found that *to implement* means 'to carry out (something concrete).'

Is ***implement improvement*** awkward English?

Comment: It's good alliteration.

Comment: I think we'd need to see context. "Implement improvements" can certainly be used fluently.

Comment: To my ear it has to be used with the plural "improvements"  If you were implementing one improvement, you would say "implement this improvement" or "implement the improvement"

Comment: @DavidM Right. But the plural can be attached to another word. Maybe that's cheating. "*It is the Transportation Director's responsibility to implement improvement projects as they are required.*" It can also be used in section titles where omitted words are common, like "Implementing Improvement Plan" where there is an implied "an" or "the".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree with that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "Implement Improvements" could well mean that we are improving knives & forks and making them better.

Answer (score 2):

It's gobbledygook -- manager-speak.

Yes, you can say "implement some improvements in X." But in most cases you should just say "*improve* X". Or if *how* you improved X is important then choose a more specific verb than "implement" -- say what you did.

Generally speaking, "implement improvements" is a candidate for a good game of Bullshit Bingo, along with "reach out to", "seek input from", "going forward", "establish a dialog with", "leverage", and so on.

It is *not* about being more *formal*. It's about being more highfalutin. It's about talking more to say less.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword_bingo
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword_compliant
- http://sweary.com/business-buzzword-generator/

Answer (score 0):

It seems unnecessarily formal.

With a definite or indefinite article to limit the sense of 'improvement', where the reference is to a previously defined, or agreed action or set of actions, and the agent is clear, it could work.

However, consider 'carry out', 'realise', 'make' or even just, 'improve' - all of which would be simpler and clearer, although they may not convey what you want to say precisely, in which case, see above.

Comment: It's used in a formal report written by a non-native English speaker. But I really doubt the collocation.